# working on a post end point but getting an error when using async arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, asynchronous, endpoint

```
app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {});
```

I get an error at the arrow which reads
Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Comment: What's the "unexpected token" in the error message? Is it `=>`?

Comment: The error occurred due to incompatibility of the development environment and eslint parsing. So I guess first you should check and make sure that your development environment is supported which version of eslint. The error you have posted is occurred due to es6 does not support.

Comment: Please add your eslintrc, package.json, node and npm version for more details.

Comment: thanks ill check it out now

Comment: yeah it was the arrown